# unexpected null in start extracting text in InputMethodService

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am developing soft keyboard every thing works fine but when i change `orientation` following error occurs

`"Unexpected null in startExtractingText : mExtractedText = null, input connection = com.android.internal.view.InputConnectionWrapper"`

and close the inputview as well

i don't know how to solve this please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found problem 
when External application force close Input-view it will throw

> start extracting text null

Comment: Then what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. I have resolved this issue. In my case , I was adding my custom view on overrided method  setExtractView(View view). But I was not removing views first.

Let me explain :

```
@Override
public void setExtractView(View view) {
  // You have to do this if you are not doing so
  view.removeAllViews() ; // This is the line 
  view.addView(yourView) ; // Here you can put your own  Custom view 
  super.setExtractView(view);
}
```

This is working for me.I hope this will help you.